# need to know how to code a countdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm fairly new to coding in general, but I have a decent grasp on things. I am coding a bot for Discord and the main command I need is to start a countdown from 5. for example, someone says !startqueue and it will start counting from 5 and will stop once it gets to zero. I would be able to find the answer somewhere else if it didn't have to send individual messages. I don't know if this is making any sense so please ask for clarification if need be.

this is the code that controls the !roll function. it rolls a random number from 1-6 (this is just to give an idea of how to code looks for a working discord command).

```
    const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
class DiceRollCommand extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'roll',
            group: 'random',
            memberName: 'roll',
            description: 'Rolls a die' ,
        });
    }
    async run(message, args) {
        var roll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        message.reply("You Rolled a " + roll);
    }
}
module.exports = DiceRollCommand;
```

below this is the basic code i have setup for the !queue command

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
class QueueCommand extends commando.Commando {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'Queue Start',
            group: 'random',
            memberName: 'startQueue',
            description: 'Starts the queue' ,
        });
    }
}
```

this is just the rest of the code that i have, just so you see all the code i see also.

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando') ;
const bot = new commando.CommandoClient();

bot.registry.registerGroup('random', 'Random') ;
bot.registry.registerDefaults();
bot.registry.registerCommandsIn(__dirname + "/commands") ;

bot.login('no token');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple countdown:

```js
let count = 5

const counter = setInterval(() => {
  if (count > 0) {
    console.log(count)
    count--
  } else {
    clearInterval(counter)
  }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: How do I make it so it edits the message not one by one